# How to publish a JAX-WS via HttpService in OSGi

Tags: java, web-services, osgi, jax-ws

I have a HttpService running in OSGi. Via this service I want to provide a (Stateful) Web Service, but I don't understand how to make my annotated classes accessible via the HttpService.

The HttpService offers `registerServlet(java.lang.String alias, javax.servlet.Servlet servlet, java.util.Dictionary initparams, HttpContext context)` that I have used before to offer my JAX-RS Services using Jersey. In this scenario the `ServletContainer` does the job. I want to offer my Web Services in the same way.

It seems to be clear that I require a `Servlet`. The JAX-WS RI provides a `WSServlet` classes that seems to be the right thing. It can be instantiated, but how can I register my Web Services to this Servlet? JAX-WS RI offers an `Endpoint` to define a communication endpoint. But I cannot find a way to connect this instance to the Servlet.

Has anybody an idea, how to get the job done?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way how to deploy endpoint is

```
    MyService svcImpl = new MyService();
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(svcImpl);
    endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/myws/mysvc");
```

If you need deployment using servlet, check this doc:

https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.10/docs/ch03.html#users-guide-war-file-packaging

In web.xml you'll find necessary info. Be aware that the initialisation of endpoint(s) is done in

```
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
```

- you should be able to use the ContextListener with HttpService somehow too. During initialisation descriptor sun-jaxws.xml is parsed.